# Trouble performing HQL: TransientObjectException

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have a "Profissional" entity that has a @ManyToOne unidirectional relationship with "City". Then, when executing query like following...

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity=Cidade.class)
@JoinColumn(name="IDE_CIDADE_DOMICILIO_FISCAL",nullable=true)
public Cidade getCidadeDomicilioFiscal() {
    return cidadeDomicilioFiscal;
}

return query.scroll();
```

...this hibernate exception appears. I've also tried including cascade = CascadeType.ALL on Profissional side, without effects. And also @Cascade annotation of Hibernate, like this:

```
@Cascade(CascadeType.SAVED_UPDATE)
```

without any effect!

```
11:03:05,427 INFO  [STDOUT] Hibernate: 
    select
        nomeacao0_.IDE_COMPETENCIA_JUDICIAL as col_0_0_,
        cidade2_.DES_CIDADE as col_1_0_,
        unidade1_.DES_UNIDADE as col_2_0_,
        categoriap5_.NOME_CATEGORIA as col_3_0_,
        solicitaco3_.NUM_SOLICITACAO as col_4_0_,
        processoju9_.NUM_PROCESSO as col_5_0_,
        processoju9_.NOME_ASSISTIDO as col_6_0_,
        profissao8_.NOME_PROFISSAO as col_7_0_,
        especialid7_.NOME_ESPECIALIDADE as col_8_0_,
        solicitaco3_.DATA_PRESTACAO_SERVICO as col_9_0_,
        profission6_.NOME_RAZAO_SOCIAL_PROFISSIONAL as col_10_0_,
        profission6_.NUM_CPF_CNPJ as col_11_0_,
        solicitaco3_.VAL_BRUTO as col_12_0_,
        nomeacao0_.QTD_ASSISTIDOS as col_13_0_,
        cidade10_.DES_CIDADE as col_14_0_ 
    from
        O_AJ.NOMEACAO nomeacao0_ 
    inner join
        O_AJ.UNIDADE unidade1_ 
            on nomeacao0_.IDE_UNIDADE=unidade1_.IDE_UNIDADE 
    inner join
        O_AJ.CIDADE cidade2_ 
            on unidade1_.COD_CIDADE=cidade2_.COD_CIDADE 
    inner join
        O_AJ.SOLICITACAO_PAGAMENTO solicitaco3_ 
            on nomeacao0_.IDE_NOMEACAO=solicitaco3_.IDE_NOMEACAO 
    inner join
        O_AJ.UNIDADE unidade4_ 
            on solicitaco3_.IDE_UNIDADE=unidade4_.IDE_UNIDADE 
    inner join
        O_AJ.CATEGORIA_PROFISSAO categoriap5_ 
            on nomeacao0_.IDE_CATEGORIA_PROFISSAO=categoriap5_.IDE_CATEGORIA_PROFISSAO 
    inner join
        O_AJ.PROFISSIONAL profission6_ 
            on nomeacao0_.IDE_PROFISSIONAL=profission6_.IDE_PROFISSIONAL 
    inner join
        O_AJ.CIDADE cidade10_ <<===== HERE IS MY JOIN
            on profission6_.IDE_CIDADE_DOMICILIO_FISCAL=cidade10_.COD_CIDADE 
    left outer join
        O_AJ.ESPECIALIDADE especialid7_ 
            on nomeacao0_.IDE_ESPECIALIDADE=especialid7_.IDE_ESPECIALIDADE 
    left outer join
        O_AJ.PROFISSAO profissao8_ 
            on nomeacao0_.IDE_PROFISSAO=profissao8_.IDE_PROFISSAO 
    left outer join
        O_AJ.PROCESSO_JUDICIAL processoju9_ 
            on nomeacao0_.IDE_PROCESSO_JUDICIAL=processoju9_.IDE_PROCESSO_JUDICIAL 
    where
        unidade1_.IDE_UNIDADE=unidade4_.IDE_UNIDADE 
        and (
            categoriap5_.IDE_CATEGORIA_PROFISSAO in (
                '3'
            )
        ) 
        and (
            nomeacao0_.IDE_COMPETENCIA_JUDICIAL in (
                '2'
            )
        ) 
        and (
            solicitaco3_.DATA_SOLICITACAO_PAGAMENTO between ? and ?
        ) 
        and unidade1_.IND_ATIVO=1 
        and unidade1_.IDE_REGIAO=? 
        and (
            profission6_.IDE_CIDADE_DOMICILIO_FISCAL is not null
        ) 
        and cidade10_.COD_CIDADE=? 
        and length(profission6_.NUM_CPF_CNPJ)<=11 
        and (
            solicitaco3_.COD_SITUACAO_SOLICITACAO in (
                4
            )
        ) 
    order by
        nomeacao0_.IDE_COMPETENCIA_JUDICIAL,
        unidade1_.COD_CIDADE,
        nomeacao0_.IDE_CATEGORIA_PROFISSAO,
        unidade1_.DES_UNIDADE
11:03:05,432 ERROR [STDERR] javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: /pagamento/consultarsolicitacoes/consultarsolicitacoes_principal.xhtml @338,25 actionListener="#{visao.verificaConteudoRelatorio}": org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: cjf.aj.comum.negocio.Cidade
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.facelets.el.LegacyMethodBinding.invoke(LegacyMethodBinding.java:73)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:89)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:180)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:158)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:346)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:32)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.JFSCLifecycle.executePhase(JFSCLifecycle.java:74)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.JFSCLifecycle.execute(JFSCLifecycle.java:49)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:139)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:147)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.xmlfilter.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:127)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.ajax4jsf.framework.ajax.xmlfilter.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:277)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.debug.hot.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:60)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
11:03:05,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
11:03:05,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at cjf.aj.comum.apresentacao.AJMultiPartFilter.doFilter(AJMultiPartFilter.java:77)
11:03:05,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
11:03:05,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
11:03:05,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.web.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:43)
11:03:05,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at cjf.aj.comum.apresentacao.AJCharacterEncoding.doFilter(AJCharacterEncoding.java:42)
11:03:05,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
11:03:05,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
11:03:05,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
11:03:05,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
11:03:05,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
11:03:05,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at cjf.aj.comum.log.AJGExceptionFilter.doFilter(AJGExceptionFilter.java:25)
11:03:05,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
11:03:05,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
11:03:05,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
11:03:05,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:202)
11:03:05,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
11:03:05,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
11:03:05,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
11:03:05,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:175)
11:03:05,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:432)
11:03:05,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:74)
11:03:05,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
11:03:05,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
11:03:05,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.tc5.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:156)
11:03:05,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
11:03:05,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
11:03:05,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:869)
11:03:05,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:664)
11:03:05,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
11:03:05,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.MasterSlaveWorkerThread.run(MasterSlaveWorkerThread.java:112)
11:03:05,435 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
11:03:05,436 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: cjf.aj.comum.negocio.Cidade
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

It's okay,

this version of hibernate wasn't accepting serializable objects as parameters.

```
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.0.SP1</version>
```